# creating a delayed hide/shrink menu when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html

I've seen this type of hiding/shrinking menu when the user scrolls and am trying to create one. I've tried reasearching it but don't even know what type it is called.

example used here 
http://www.cpbgroup.com/

my menu is similar layout

```
<nav id="s-nav-wrap">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>" id="s-logo"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8 align-right" id="s-nav">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

            <div id="btn-home">
            <a href="<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>">HOME</a>
            </div>  
        </div>

    </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These can be referred to a flyout, slide and push or side menus depending on the functionality you are looking for, here are a few tutorials to get you started.

[Slide and push](http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions)

[Side Menu](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2013/06/24/creating-a-swipeable-side-menu-for-the-web/)

Do some more searching and I am sure you will find something you like.

Comment: these aren't exactly what I'm looking for, but thank you for the names i'll be able to hopefully narrow my search. I don't want to click and have it show up. I want it to be there then animate away when the user scrolls

Comment: Are you referring to something like this [Flyout Menu](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CufonizedFlyOutMenu/)?

Comment: the one i'm looking for is just like the example link i provided. Not when you click it, just when you scroll down, it stays for a bit then animates up and away